# compare sum of column values in python

Tags: python

I have a csv file loaded in a python object. 15 of the columns contains binary values. I have several thousands rows.

I want to count the sum of the binary values of each of the columns and sort the result ascendingly.

I only made it to:

```
sum1=sum(products['1'])
sum2=sum(products['2'])
sum3=sum(products['3'])
....
...
sum15=sum(products['15'])
```

and process the result manually. Is there a programmatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
sorted_sum = sorted([sum(products[i]) for i in range(1, 16)])
```

sorted_sum is the sorted list of column sums. However, I believe the index should run from 0 to 14, not 1 to 15.

Comment: what would this look like if the columns have some names instead of numbers?

Comment: then you should put all the column names in a list, says COLUMN_HEADERS, and replace `for i in range(1, 16)` with `for i in COLUMN_HEADERS`

Answer (score 1):

you will find the solution here :

```
with open("file.csv") as fin:
headerline = fin.next()
list_sum_product=[]
for i in range(15):
    total = 0
    for row in csv.reader(fin):
        total += int(row[i])
    list_sum_product.append(total)
print sorted(list_sum_product)
```